# C3P0 0.9.5-pre6 with Jetty 9.1

Tags: mysql, jetty, jndi, c3p0

I have been successfully using `C3P0 0.9.1.2` with `Jetty 8.1.13.v20130916`. In my Jetty server instance, using a Jetty XML configuration file, I bind a C3P0-backed `DataSource` to JNDI. Then my web application looks up this `DataSource` by name. This has always worked.

I'm currently migrating to `C3P0 0.9.5-pre6` and to `Jetty 9.1.0.v20131115`.

Since this migration, C3P0 connection pooling doesn't work anymore. I have tried different unpooled and pooled strategies.

Since the migration, the following two **unpooled** binding strategies **work**:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  ....
  <!-- raw mysql connection without C3P0 - THIS WORKS! -->
  <New id="jdbc-myds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
        <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myds?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</Set>
        <Set name="User">user</Set>
        <Set name="Password">pass</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

---

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  ....
  <!-- UNPOOLED c3p0 factory - THIS WORKS! -->
  <New id="jdbc-myds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <Call class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources" name="unpooledDataSource">
        <Arg>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myds?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</Arg>
        <Arg>user</Arg>
        <Arg>pass</Arg>
      </Call>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

---

---

Since the migration, the following two **pooled** binding strategies **don't work**:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  ....
  <!-- typical C3P0 pool configuration - THIS DOESN'T WORK FOR ME SINCE MIGRATION -->
  <New id="jdbc-myds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <Set name="DriverClass">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</Set>
        <Set name="JdbcUrl">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myds?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</Set>
        <Set name="User">user</Set>
        <Set name="Password">password</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

---

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  ....
  <!-- wrapping the successfully working C3P0 unpooled DataSource in a pooled DataSource - THIS DOESN'T WORK -->
  <New id="jdbc-myds" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/myds</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <Call class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources" name="pooledDataSource">
        <Arg>
          <Call class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources" name="unpooledDataSource">
            <Arg>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myds?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</Arg>
            <Arg>user</Arg>
            <Arg>pass</Arg>
          </Call>
        </Arg>
      </Call>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

---

---

In the unsuccessful cases, when visiting the server, the server's HTTP response is a Jetty-served **HTTP ERROR: 503, Service Unavailable**.
Even though the server-startup logs say that the JNDI resource has been successfully registered, at the moment I am trying to access that JNDI resource by name inside my web application, it doesn't exist anymore: Calling

```
DataSource myds = new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myds");
```

throws an `InvalidClassException` and a `NamingException`:

```
17:08:33.907 [main] WARN  jndi -
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7086951306718003710, local class serialVersionUID = 7806429541739165290
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at com.mchange.v2.ser.SerializableUtils.deserializeFromByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:132) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.6.3.jar:0.2.6.3]
        at com.mchange.v2.ser.SerializableUtils.fromByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:111) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.6.3.jar:0.2.6.3]
        at com.mchange.v2.naming.JavaBeanObjectFactory.createPropertyMap(JavaBeanObjectFactory.java:98) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.6.3.jar:0.2.6.3]
        at com.mchange.v2.naming.JavaBeanObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(JavaBeanObjectFactory.java:59) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.6.3.jar:0.2.6.3]
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:476) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:518) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:533) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:468) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:551) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:117) [jetty-jndi-9.1.0.v20131115.jar:9.1.0.v20131115]
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [na:1.7.0_45]
        at com.example.spring.config.MainConfig.dataSource(MainConfig.java:65) [classes/:na]
        at com.example.spring.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8673699d.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) [cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at com.example.spring.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8673699d$$FastClassByCGLIB$$554d588d.invoke(<generated>) [cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280) [spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at com.example.spring.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8673699d.dataSource(<generated>) [cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:149) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at  .............(shortened for brevity)
17:08:33.908 [main] ERROR c.example.spring.config.MainConfig - Couldn't either create InitialContext or couldn't lookup jdbc/myds
javax.naming.NamingException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7086951306718003710, local class serialVersionUID = 7806429541739165290
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:485)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:518)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.local.localContextRoot.lookup(localContextRoot.java:533)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:468)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:536)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:551)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:117)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at com.example.spring.config.MainConfig.dataSource(MainConfig.java:65)
        at com.example.spring.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8673699d.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>)
        at com.example.spring.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8673699d$$FastClassByCGLIB$$554d588d.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:280)
        at com.example.spring.config.MainConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8673699d.dataSource(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at .............(shortened for brevity)
```

Can anyone see any misconfiguration on my side?

Comment: Do you have `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource` in your WebAppClassloader and your Server classloader for that incompatible classchange error to occur?

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me into the right direction...!

Answer (score 1):

@Joakim's suggestion helped me locate the problem's source and find a solution. The problem's source didn't have anything to do with Jetty 9.1, instead it stemmed from a Maven dependency library having a transitive dependency on an older C3P0 version `0.9.1.1`:

My web application uses the Quartz scheduler, so my application's `pom.xml` included

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.0` has a dependency on `c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.1`.

That old version of C3P0 got into conflict with the newer `com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5-pre6` that I have in my Jetty server instance's `lib/etc/` directory.

---

The solution to my problem is to explicitly exclude Quartz' dependency on that old C3P0 artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
                <groupId>c3p0</groupId> 
                <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

At least for my specific Quartz usage, Quartz still works well.